# Twilio Web Client

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

Any one knows if it's possible to customize the Twilio web client?
I want to remove the Twilio Icon and add my custom icon, or at least change the size,background and add my custom background.

Looking at the documentation I don't see an option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can contact their support. I'm sure they have the definitive answer

Comment: Already done that and waiting for the answer but was wondering if anyone has done that already and can share their workaround. Not sure why one would down vote this simple and clear question but I guess people have their reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer back from Twilio and I'm sharing so others who don't know can use it and avoid getting voted down by smarter people who are annoyed.
As per response I got from them developers are allowed to customize the css by copying it from the twilio site and saving it locally and modifying is including changing the logo and colours and so on.
Simple enough I guess. Hope this comes handy.